# Combining weightlifting and martial arts

Tags: weightlifting, strength, martial-arts

**MY HISTORY**

I am a 27 year old man that has been weightlifting seriously for more than one year now. I have also doing some martial arts before, and want to get back at it again.

```
Height: 178cm/5 ft 10 inch
Weight: 90kg/198lbs
```

**These are my PRs:**

```
Deadlift (regular) eq - 140kg
Squat eq - 115kg
Bench press - 80kg
```

**MY CURRENT SETUP**

I'm going through a existing program. You'll see that 4x6-10xWEIGHT is 4 sets and 6 repetitions the first week. Then we do 4x8xWEIGHT the next week and then 4x10xWEIGHT and then increase to a higher weight. The same goes for the first set 1x3-5xWEIGHT.

```
Monday - Workout 1 - Deadlift - 1x3-5xWEIGHT (Maximum effort set)
Monday - Workout 1 - Deadlift - 4x6-10xWEIGHT (Less weight and higher volume)
Monday - Workout 1 - Military Press - 1x3-5xWEIGHT (Maximum effort set)
Monday - Workout 1 - Military Press - 4x6-10xWEIGHT (Less weight and higher volume)
Wednesday - Workout 2 - Bench Press - 1x3-5xWEIGHT (Maximum effort set)
Wednesday - Workout 2 - Bench Press - 4x6-10xWEIGHT (Less weight and higher volume)
Wednesday - Workout 2 - Assistance Chin Ups - 4x6-10xWEIGHT
Wednesday - Workout 2 - Bent-over barbell row with overhand grip - 4x6-10xWEIGHT
Friday - Workout 3 - Squats - 1x3-5xWEIGHT (Maximum effort set)
Friday - Workout 3 - Squats - 4x6-10xWEIGHT (Less weight and higher 
Friday - Workout 3 - Chins - 4xMAX
```

**MY GOAL**

**My goal for weightlifting to the next summer:**

```
Deadlift (regular) eq - 180+kg
Squat eq - 150+kg
Bench press - 100+kg
```

My goal is to include two times of a week tuesday and thursday for martial arts as well. I just loved it before i remember, but quit because I had a damage to my rib, it was a crack and I couldn't doing it for a time and then time just went on...

The question here though is can I keep increasing in results in my weightlifting for building strength and mass as well as the martial arts training at the same time? Do I get enough of rest for my body to recover and get stronger?

Is it recommended combining these together?

Comment: The man, myth, and legend Bruce Lee famously combined martial arts with strength training. It’s certainly possible and many have done it both before and after Lee. However, the real question isn’t whether you should or shouldn’t combine them, but rather how best to combine them.

Comment: @JustSnilloc How would that be to best combine them. Any ideas?

Comment: What are your goals in the martial arts, and what style will you be taking? I'm a 5th degree, and what I would recommend for grappling/bjj/mma is much different than I would recommend for Muay Thai, vs tkd, etc. Also if you are going to be a forms/weapons competitor vs mainly sparring, there are differences in training.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to the site! +1 for a good question with a lot of good background info. :)

Comment: @JohnP Thanks :) I will be doing Karate. Before I did Taekwondo. But I think I would like Karate more. My goals of the Karate would be to be more flexible, more body control, better mental strength and focus and so forth. Self defence.

Comment: Ok, but what is your emphasis? Forms? Sparring? General health?

Comment: @JohnP Sparring and forms. Health is of course important, but not my number one. I'm not really 100% sure of my goal with the Karate yet. I think that will evolve with time I guess as I'm doing it.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but you should check out the Tactical Barbell books, they're designed exactly for this kind of thing (I'd recommend TB I and II, though you might be able to get away with just I). You can also check out https://www.reddit.com/r/tacticalbarbell/